# android - Корявый айтем в ListView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Делаю чат, столкнулся с проблемой, сообщения слева (чужие) выглядят нормально, а справа (свои) - нет. 
Откройте в дизайне, бэкграундом служит облачко. Скриншоты скинуть не могу, не знаю как это делать с мобильного.

Подробнее:
Сообщения справа растягиваются на всю ширину экрана, обращение и текст сообщения находятся в горизонтальном `LinearLayout`, под ним еще один с полным ником и временем отправки. Оба `LinearLayout` находятся в `RelativeLayout` с бэкграундом облачка. Облачко слева от фотографии отправителя. Почему "правые" сообщения растягиваются?

**item_right.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:gravity="right">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_msg_right"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/messagebox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reply_marker"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Reply"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:text="Привет"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/messagebox"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wolfram"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#A40DFF"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/full_nick"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="12:00"
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/first_char_nick"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_sender_right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="W"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему растягивается - я и сам не понял, но если вы используете

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

вместо

```
<RelativeLayout
```

То все станет так, как вам надо (насколько я понял)

`<offtop>за 4 года работы Андроид девелопером, я так и не осилил все тонкости RelativeLayout</offtop>`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)